# How to solve second order equation in matrix form?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

How do you solve second order equation by writing it as a coupled linear system in matrix form: $y''+y'+y=0$.

Comment: Let $x_1 -=y, x_2 = y'$ and write out the equations for $x_k$ in terms of $x_k$. The resulting matrix can be diagonalised, and the resulting two first order equations are easy to solve.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
\text{Let } z & = y'. \\
\text{Then } z' + z + y & = 0, \\
\text{so } -z-y & =z'. \\[12pt]
\text{Hence } \begin{bmatrix} y \\ z \end{bmatrix} ' & = \left[\begin{array}{rr} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & -1 \end{array} \right] \begin{bmatrix} y \\ z \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}